# Doesn't work saving of document in mongoDb(mongoose)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have next code:

```
var Numerator = new Schema({
    id: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    value: {
        type:Number,
        required: true
    },
    ips: {
        type: Schema.Types.Mixed,
        default: {},
        required: true
    }
});
```

There's to ways to save data in 'ips':

```
res.ips = {1:1, 2:2};
```

and

```
var obj = {1:1, 2:2};
res.ips = obj;
```

when i use second method i have problems with saving the document, i tried many ways and understand that problem in using object-variable when editing the document.
But this variable is alive, while function wating for saving-callback from mongoose.
what am i doing wrong?
in result i getting error: "not okForStorage"

Comment: Did you actually call the `save()` method?

Comment: @NeilLunn of course:) i call it, and if i don't use the .markModified method, document saving correctly

Comment: Then have you not just answered your own question? Why call `markModified` when you know you are actually modifying that value?

Comment: @NeilLunn i call it, because i read in documentation http://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html
that to save mixed type value in document correctly, you need to use this method after changes

Comment: Can you edit your question to include your schema and more of your relevant code?

Comment: @JohnyHK ok, i did it

Comment: @Foker thanks, your comment works also for me.